# How to prevent a positioned element with transform added from being added as part of document flow?

Tags: css

You can see an interactive example [here][1].
I want the blue div with `transform: translate` added to sit below the red div but without the scroll (so without being a part of the document flow). (I want to animate the blue div to appear in front of the red one but can't do it properly since it's part of the document flow).

Why adding `transform` property instantly converts a `position: absolute` element that is no longer part of the document flow to an element that is part of the document flow?

Thank you!

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.inset-0 {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.h-96 {
  height: 24rem;
}

.w-96 {
  width: 24rem;
}

.translate-y-full {
  --tw-translate-y: 100%;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
}

.overflow-y-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.bg-yellow-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(250 204 21 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-red-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(248 113 113 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-blue-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(96 165 250 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

```html
<div class="relative h-96 w-96 overflow-y-scroll bg-yellow-400">
  <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-red-400">
    <div class="absolute inset-0 translate-y-full bg-blue-400"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  [1]: https://play.tailwindcss.com/xDKID0dPV1
```

Comment: To learn more about why scrollbar takes effect when the view is somehow extended ( like in your case with translate Y) read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/scrollbar_role. I would argue that the browser does this how one would expect - your solution is simply to add `overflow-hidden` to the relative positioned parent element.

Comment: To put it simple, I can't use `overflow: hidden`, but thank you! :)

Comment: if you don't want the scrollbar then why are you using `overflow-y: scroll`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are nesting absolutely positioned elements but here is how I would lay things out (scaled for this snippet) without knowing your rationale.

```css
:root {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --height: 8rem;
  --width: 8rem;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.inset-0 {
  top: 0px;
  right: -17px;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.h-96 {
  height: var(--height);
}

.w-96 {
  width: var(--width);
}

.translate-y-full {
  --tw-translate-y: 100%;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
}

.bg-yellow-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(250 204 21 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-red-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(248 113 113 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-blue-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(96 165 250 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

```html
<div class="relative h-96 w-96 bg-yellow-400">
  <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-red-400">
    <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-blue-400 translate-y-full"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```